# Objective C, Download a photo from web and show as a full screen

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have a thumbnail image and I have an original image(about 1200 * 1600) on my server. What is the best way for users to see the full screen of the original image on iPhone?

I could send HTTP request to download the image but how can I show the image on the full screen? Also. If I download the full size image then is this bed for memory management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIImageView` in your UI, download the fullscreen image to disk, create a new image using UIImage's imageWithContentsOfFile:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

and eventually assign the `image` property of your `UIImageView` instance to this newly created image.

To download the fullscreen image, do not use synchronous methods like `NSData`'s `dataWithContentsOfURL` or it will block your UI. Instead use the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection`.

See the *Loading Data Asynchronously* section of [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

The full image seem to be appr. 12 times larger than the standard iPhone 320x480 screen. I think you can pre-render a down-scaled image to download for this and not feel about that.

Automator is a simple way to batch process this for you. See this vid.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7p081Ui9WY